# How to make a plugin python function available to IDA's console?

Tags: idapython, ida-plugin

I want to have utility functions shared between all databases, for example:

```py
from idautils import *
from idaapi import *
from idc import *
from ida_name import *

def FindFunctionImpl(FunctionNameToFind):
    for SegmentAddress in Segments():
        for FunctionAddress in Functions(SegmentAddress, get_segm_end(SegmentAddress)):
            FunctionName = get_func_name(FunctionAddress)
            DemangledName = get_long_name(FunctionAddress)
            if DemangledName.find(FunctionNameToFind) != -1:
                print(f"0x{FunctionAddress:x}:{DemangledName}")

class ExamplePlugin(idaapi.plugin_t):
    flags = idaapi.PLUGIN_DRAW
    comment = ""
    help = ""
    wanted_name = "Example"

    def init(self):
        print("ExamplePlugin initialized")
        global FindFunction = FindFunctionImpl
        return idaapi.PLUGIN_KEEP # On garde le plugin chargé en mémoire

    def run(self, arg):
        return

    def term(self):
        pass

def PLUGIN_ENTRY():
    return ExamplePlugin()
```

But it doesn't want to let me use neither `FindFunction` nor `FindFunctionImpl` from the console. Says "name isn't defined" in the console. It prints in the console that the plugin is initialized.

Comment: Put your function definitions inside the idapythonrc.py file that IDAPython executes on startup. This is one of the installation methods of the minsc plugin that I maintain which is a library that provides something similar to what you're starting to do (https://arizvisa.github.io/ida-minsc/install.html#installation-of-ida-minsc). The idapythonrc.py method for initiailzing the Python interpreter is also documented at the Hex-Rays blog (https://hex-rays.com/blog/igors-tip-of-the-week-33-idas-user-directory-idausr/).

Comment: @AliRizvi-Santiago please add this as an answer

Answer (score 2):

1. Separate out `FindFunctionImpl` into its own `.py` file, say `FuncUtil.py`.
2. Put the directory containing that file into your system's `$PYTHONPATH`.
3. Invoke it from the IDAPython console as `FuncUtil.FindFunctionImpl`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a path to your plugin script in one of the `plugins.list` files, this will tell IDA to load the plugin everytime you open an IDB. You can run plugins from `Edit/Plugins` menu.

It's a shame HexRays haven't put up any docs on that to this day, but you can find a decent explanation in [Sark's reference](https://sark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/installation.html).

Comment: `plugins.list` is not used by IDA but seems to be a Sark feature.